# Where did Cura get this ghost layer from?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, layer-shifting, ghosting

I designed a very simple boat in Tinkercad and then I printed it. No problem, but I wanted it a bit wider. So I made it wider in Tinkercad and printed it again. This second version has a crack in the right side and it had some PLA mess in the boat. I thought nothing of it and printed it again. This third print also has this crack and some leftover PLA in the boat. So I checked out the design in Tinkercad, Cura, and in the print preview in Cura. Below are the results:

[image: Screenshot of a boat modeled in Tinkercad]

[image: Screenshot of a boat rendered in Cura's preview]

[image: Screenshot of a boat rendered in Cura's preview showing a ghost layer after the model was modified]

As you can see, the last image (the print preview) suddenly has this one (yellow-colored) layer which moves across the inner part of the boat. Exactly there, the boat also misses one layer from the hull, making a crack in the hull.

I then recreated the side in Tinkercad, exported another STL, and imported it into Cura again. But the ghost layer is still there. I finally tried all sorts of things, and when I recreated a little hole in the bow of the boat, the ghost layer went away.

I now wonder, how could this create the ghost layer across the inside of the boat at a place where the hole wasn't even located? And also, why could it only pop up on the print preview, and not in any of the other views?

Comment: What version of Cura are you using? Is it the most current version? Have you tried other versions?

Comment: Looks like an error in slicing. Check other slicer or other version of Cura, and see if this problem still occurs.

Comment: Your STL files is probably incorrect as caused by the Tinkercad model to STL translation. There are a few questions to be found on this issue. If you're lucky, @Trish may answer your question.

Comment: @agarza - I was using cura version 4.13.2 and I saw that the latest is 5.2.1 which I just installed. Using that, the weird ghost line is indeed vanished. Thanks for the tip! I install most of my software using an automatic updating system (apt/flatpak/snap), but I've must have installed this using something else.